# Is there an option to automatically make solve return the principal value of inverse trig functions?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I am porting some of my Maple packages to Mathematica. In Maple, `solve(sin(y)=x,y)` returns `arcsin(x)` and I'd like to get same output from Mathematica.

[image]

This is all done in code. I do not know before hand if the expression will have trig function or not in it. So I need some option or setting to tell Mathematica to automatically assume principal values as this is what is common in other CAS systems. Same with Fricas

```
                      FriCAS Computer Algebra System 
                            Version: FriCAS 1.3.8
(1) -> solve(sin(y)=x,y)

   (1)  [y = asin(x)]
```

Right now

```
ClearAll[x, y]
Solve[ Sin[y] == x , y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can't add explicit assumptions, because the program does not know if the input is trig function or not. I looked and looked and can't find an option to tell `Solve` to use the principal value, other than explicitly hardcoding things, but this will not work, since I do not know the form of the expression.

The principal inverses are listed in the following table at Wikipedia which what Mathematica also know.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

[image]

A global setting or option which makes Mathematica automatically return `y->ArcSin[x]` when solving `Sin[y] == x` for `y` will be great.

Comment: You may  wrap the functions with "Mod" and define your own.

Comment: You can wrap all the input `Sin`s with `Inactive`. `Solve[ Inactive[Sin][y] == x , y]//Activate` gives `{{y -> ArcSin[x]}}`

Comment: @yurie Interesting. I think it's worth posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is only to replicate the table in the OP.

```
Grid[Catenate[{{{"Name", "Usual notation", "Definition", 
     "Domain of x for real result" , 
     "Range of usual principal value (rads)", 
     "Range of usual principal value (Degrees)"}}
   , {#
      , #[x]
      , TraditionalForm[InverseFunction[#][y]]
      , FunctionDomain[#[x], x, Reals]
      , FunctionRange[#[x], x, y]
      , FunctionRange[#[x] 180/\[Pi], x, y] // N
      } & /@
    {ArcSin, ArcCos, ArcTan, ArcCot, ArcSec, ArcCsc}}
  ]
 , ItemSize -> {{6, 6, 6, 12, 16, 16}, {3, 1}}
 , Alignment -> {Center, Center}
 , Dividers -> All
 , Spacings -> {1, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases we can freeze all the definitions of `Sin`,

```
Solve[Inactive[Sin][y]==x,y,InverseFunctions->True]//Activate
Solve[Hold[Sin][y]==x,y,InverseFunctions->True]//ReleaseHold
Solve["sin"[y]==x,y,InverseFunctions->True]/."sin"->Sin
(*{{y -> ArcSin[x]}}*)
```

`Inactivate` has the advantage that `Inactivate[expr,Sin]` will wrap all the `Sin` in `expr` automatically.

For less simpler ones, e.g.

```
Sin[2y]//TrigExpand
(*2 Cos[y] Sin[y]*)
```

If we inactivate both `Sin` and `Cos`, the relation in between is lost and the equation `Sin[2y]==x` can not be solved. In this case we need e.g.

```
eq=Sin[2y]//TrigExpand//ReplaceAll[Cos[arg_]:>Sqrt[1-Sin[arg]^2]]//Inactivate[#,Sin]&
```

[image]
then

```
Solve[eq==x,y,InverseFunctions->True]//Activate
```

gives
[image]
comparing with

```
Solve[2 Cos[y] Sin[y]==x,y]//FullSimplify
```

[image]
Not too bad.

If your input is algebraic with respect to `Tan[y/2]`, maybe replace all the trigonometric functions into `Tan[y/2]` is a better choice.